# How to find the maximum volume?

Tags: optimization, vectors

Let $\vec u$ and $\vec v $ be unit vectors. If $\vec w$ is a vector such that $\vec w$+($\vec w \times \vec u)=\vec v$, If the maximum volume of the parallelepiped formed by $\vec v$,$\vec u$,$\vec w$ is $p$, then $12p$  is?

I have boiled down this problem to $$p=\frac{|\vec w|^2}{6}$$

But I can't seem to evaluate it further . Any guide on how to approach?
(New approaches are also welcome)

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w=au+bv+c(u\times v)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
0&=w+(w\times u)-v\\
&=au+bv+c(u\times v) +b(v\times u)+c(u\times v)\times u-v\\
&=au+bv+c(u\times v) -b(u\times v)+c(v - (u\cdot v)u)-v\\
&=[a-c(u\cdot v)]u + (b+c-1)v + (c-b)(u\times v).
\end{align}
$$
So we must have $b=c=\frac12$ and $a=\frac12(u\cdot v)$. In other words, $w$ is uniquely determined as
$$
w=\frac12\bigg[(u\cdot v)u+v+(u\times v)\bigg].
$$
It follows that $12$ times the volume of the parallelepiped formed by $u,v,w$ is equal to
$$
12\det(u,v,w)
=6\det\bigg(u,\,v,\,(u\cdot v)u+v+(u\times v)\bigg)
=6\det(u,\,v,\,u\times v)=6\|u\times v\|^2.
$$
Therefore the question is essentially asking about the maximum value of $6\|u\times v\|^2$. Clearly, this is maximised when $v\perp u$. Hence $12p=6$.